# How do I get 1 single document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've wasted about 2hrs on this stupid thing.  All I see when I log things is a `DocumentSnapshot` object and nothing every shows up in my template view.  What am I doing wrong?  Should I just be passing a whole document to my component rather than trying to get single document based on an ID?

```
//component.ts

constructor(db: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.contactCollection = db.collection('contacts');

    this.contact = this.contactCollection.doc('YYlKh7Gg7khN8L636iYE')
}

//viewTemplate.ts

{{this.contact | async}}
```

Comment: Should it not just be `{{(contact | async)?.some_prop}}`

Comment: All document fetches get all fields of the document all the time. You need to call out one of those fields for display.  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

Comment: @Rafael that was my problem.  I've been pushing data into input fields up to this point and haven't run across async with properties in a view.  I kept getting null because I was trying . {{contacts.name | async}}

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.valueChanges()` function. Added it below, now you will get the entire document back in the `viewTemplate.ts` and you can call any of the fields on it.

```
//component.ts

constructor(db: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.contactCollection = db.collection('contacts');

    this.contact = this.contactCollection.doc('YYlKh7Gg7khN8L636iYE').valueChanges();
}

//viewTemplate.ts

{{this.contact | async}}
```

.valueChanges();

Comment: When I try to access a property the view only says `null` but when I log the value from this.contact I see the whole object.  What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal answer to my comment:

`contact` is a `Promise` which must be unwrapped to get the underlying value. In the template, we need a way to convey this:

1. [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)
2. [Safe Navigation Operator `?`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) (ensures we don't try to access the unwrapped values untimely causing a runtime error)

Putting it all together in the template:

```
{{(contact | async)?.some_prop}}
```

This appropriately waits to access `some_prop` (from the Promise return value) *after* unwrapping `contact`.